# Firebase Email Link Authentication - Restrict To Certain Domain(s)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to restrict application access to certain domain names and will be using email link authentication only. In other words only users from xyz.com will receive authentication links via email and email link authentication initiated for email addresses in any other domain will fail to process.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to prevent users from getting the email link, but you can prevent them from signing up/in by implementing the `beforeCreate` and `beforeSignIn`  blocking Cloud Functions mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions).

Comment: Nice. So, looking at the [Only allowing registration from a specific domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions#only_allowing_registration_from_a_specific_domain) section it seems like the `exports.beforeCreate` blocking function would disallow the email link from being sent at all. Doesn't make sense that the auth link would get sent if _beforeCreate_ cancels the request out.

Comment: Give it a try, but I think it'll only trigger once the user clicks the link in the email.